# Maya Viewport Blackscreen

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, maya

I'm having a problem, suddenly viewport 2 on Maya often goes black. when viewport 2 in Maya turns black, cannot perform rotate, select objects, etc.

[viewport black 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fogn2.png)
[viewport black 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii69o.png)

I've tried to fix it, such as:

- Reset Maya prefs
- Try different Viewport modes
- Update graphic card drivers
- Reinstall Maya

But if I try to restart Maya, it becomes normal again but only for a moment, after that the viewport turns black.

Maya 2018
PC Spec :
[pc spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLA45.jpg)

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I got a simmiliar issue with my laptop (AMD RX560X GPU)

What happened with me is that every time I would configure the settings to my liking (best looking, lotsa eyecandy, and hopefully decent framerates) any non Game application that used Hardware accelateration would either be a black screen, or a white screen.

Solution: Reset GPU driver settings. Lose the potential eyecandy, Gain the ability to see.

Comment: thank you for sharing